# A doubling of roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

That's how it true?
[image: image 1]

or like this
[image: image 2]

thank's.

Comment: Neither is correct. Note that $u\cdot(-u)=-u^2$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\sqrt{2i}\cdot \sqrt{2i}=2i$

Comment: Or $-2i$ if you take different determinations for the square roots on the left-hand side. `;-)`